# Turning a text string of week numbers into array of values with jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql

I've been battling with this for a while:

I've got a mysql database of events happening on various weeks. For each event there is a field with the week numbers that it is occurring as a text string.

e.g. `W01-W04, W06, W08, W10`

How can i convert that that to an array of values with jquery?

e.g. `W01, W02, W03, W04 ect..`

And then how would i replace that row with a row for each week value.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: what do you mean by 'And then how would i replace that row with a row for each week value.'?

Comment: Seems to me that you're suffering the effects of a denormalized database. You should have a table for logging the weeks and other event related data and a table just for the events. If you can, change your structure, if you can't there's always a solution when it comes to string manipulations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm hoping not to have to change the structure so i'm trying to create multiple rows for each event with only one week value. I know its not a very nice way of doing things! If i can change the structure how do you link the two tables? (sorry quite new to database design)

Comment: When you say 'replace that row with a row for each week value' are you talking about rows in the MySQL table, or rows as presented to the user on the webpage? Or some other meaning that I don't yet understand?

Comment: @Tom - Events table should be something like `ID|name|description` while the EventsReports table should be something like `EventID|week|...`, So in the end you should be able to do `SELECT week FROM EventsReport WHERE EventID = 1` and even more useful queries like "Select all events between week1 and week6 that didn't happened on week3"

Comment: @David Thomas - I ment row in the mySQL table. @Ben - Thanks for your help, Its an local storage database for a iphone web app so i was trying to keep it in one table but what you suggested makes alot of sense so i'll probably rethink it. Thanks alot. Any suggestions for breaking down the string? Mainly converting W01-W04 into the individual weeks?

Comment: @Ben - Just to clarify, in the EventsReports table in your example, would the week field contain multiple comma separated values for the weeks or separate rows for each? Thanks again, its incredibly helpful.

Comment: @Tom - Just one week, it could be a timestamp or whatever you decide. If you need to have two weeks referring one event you must have two rows. When consulting the DB for the weeks of an event it should return a resulset with, in this case, two rows. This way you could expand a lot your system as you can now relate additional info to a week and/or an event.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `.split()` method on your JavaScript string:

```
string.split(',');
```

Comment: Well that's certainly going to be an important part of the solution, but there's going to be a bit more to it than just that.